# Drag and Drop an image in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for a solution to Drag and drop and image instead of browsing and selecting an image in R Shiny. Could you please anyone suggest a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny Input Reactivity Error on Drag-and-Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819250/r-shiny-input-reactivity-error-on-drag-and-drop)

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly, but maybe the package `shinyjqui` could help.

Comment: I think OP wants to import image files (`.png`, `.jpeg`, etc.) with a drag and drop ui rather than the client side of `fileDialog`.